# Dojo programatically set Grid cell to edit mode

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to programatically force a dojo.grid cell into edit mode. I've been scouring the docs and boards but I'm missing how to do this.

Comment: Look at this question and examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823231/how-to-focus-inthe-first-cell-of-a-newly-added-row-in-a-dojox-grid-datagrid/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you will be able to edit only a single cell, but maybe this question can get you started: [Dojo Grid - Switching between editable and not editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703573/dojo-grid-switching-between-editable-and-not-editable)

Basically, changing a column to allow edits boils down to something like:

```
var columnToEdit=0;
var str = grid.structure;
str[0].cells[0][columnToEdit].editable=true;
grid.set("structure",str);
```

The question linked has a bit more information and tips about how to alter the state of the grid container so that you can create a working UI.

Comment: I don't think that'll work for me.  I want to do something like: 
myCell.PutIntoEditMode()